# when data is changed, notifyListener function is called again too many times in provider flutter

Tags: android, flutter

notifyListener() is called again too many times when data changes

-this is get Api

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchProduct() async{
    final url = "http://192.168.55.102:3000/product/getAllProducts";
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    List? product;
    List<Product>? productList;
    try{
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
         product = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
         productList = product.map<Product>((e) => Product.formJson(e)).toList();
        return productList;
      }else{
        print('fail');
      }
    }catch(err){
      print(err);
    }
    return productList!;
  }
```

-This is ChangeNotifier in Provider

```
class ProductData with ChangeNotifier{
  List<Product> _list =[];
  List<Product> get list => _list;

  getAllProduct() async{
    _list = await fetchProduct();
    print('aaa');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

- This is how i use it

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<ProductData>(builder: (context, product, child) {
      product.getAllProduct();
      productList = product.list;
      return Container(
        height: 250,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: productList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ItemsProduct(
                img: productList[index].img,
                price: productList[index].price,
                name: productList[index].name);
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

it call notifyListener() many time when update data.
How to fix. thanks

i want to call notifyListener() once when update data.`

Comment: Hello. Add the code where you call the  getAllProduct() from the widget please.

Comment: sorry. i added the code, it is called in Consumer

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you call your fetch method in `build` method in Widget. When you are working with async data (or streams), it is better to choose built-in solution from Flutter that named `FutureBuilder` (or `StreamBuilder` when you are working with streams). For example:

```dart
FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
  future: product.getAllProduct(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // FutureBuilder has some states, that you can handle from snapshot. When snapshot was loaded, you can check it by snapshot.hasData.
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // Here your data available from Future. You can call your data from snapshot by snapshot.data!.
    }
    // Return loader or something else. Just show your user that products are loading.
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue that occurs because you have your request or method call inside the Consumer widget. So, each time your widget rebuilds, the method is triggered. In other words, each time you call notifyListeners(), your widget rebuilds, and the method is called again.

To solve this issue, move your method to the initState of your widget. This way, it will only be triggered once when your widget is created.

Here is an example of how to solve it.

I hope it helps you. Regards. Btw, sorry if my English is not the best.

```
class NewsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewsPage> createState() => _NewsPageState();
}

class _NewsPageState extends State<NewsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.microtask(
      () => context.read<NewsChangeNotifier>().getArticles(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('News'),
      ),
      body: Consumer<NewsChangeNotifier>(
        builder: (context, notifier, child) {
          if (notifier.isLoading) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                key: Key('progress-indicator'),
              ),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: notifier.articles.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              final article = notifier.articles[index];
              return Card(
                elevation: 2,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => ArticlePage(article: article),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(article.title),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      article.content,
                      maxLines: 4,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 8,
              vertical: 16,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i call getAllProduct() in initState, it only call once, when data is change, widget does not update

Comment: Could you provide an example of what data you need to listen for changes in your specific use case?